# How can I make a drop down menu inside a part of an image?

Tags: html, css, web, drop-down-menu

I'm a bit new to web designing. I want to create a classroom with 4 tables, each of them are clickable. I was able to create a drop down menu when clicking to an image of table with this code:

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
 font-family: Futura, ‘Century Gothic’, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}

.children {
 visibility: hidden;
 transition: visibility 0.5s; 
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 min-width: 200px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px #f3fb6b;
 z-index: 1;
 padding: 10px 10px;
}

.children a {
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
 
}

.children a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.parent:focus .children {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>
  Classroom
 </title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="table"><div tabindex="0" class="parent">
 <img src="table1.png" alt="table 1"></img>
 <div class="children">You found a paper inside the table.
  <ul>
   <li><a href="door2_paper.html">Take the paper</a></li>
   <li><a href="door2.html">Don't take the paper</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, with this method, I have to edit different margin for 4 tables, and if people zoomed in, the location of them would fall apart.

So I want to have a picture of the whole classroom with 4 tables, and the drop down menu would show up only when I click a specific table in the picture.

I had tried with image map, however, it only works with a link, not a drop down menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want...., so I just guess that you want float left 4 image as drop-down menu, and try to make it side by side??

I use part of your code to make a sample is this your need?

```css
#table{
        font-size: 0;
  width:1200px;
    }
    #table > *{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .parent {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: Futura, ‘Century Gothic’, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    }
    .children {
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: visibility 0.5s;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 200px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px #f3fb6b;
        z-index: 1;
        padding: 10px 10px;
    }
    
    .children a {
        color: black;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .children a:hover {
        background-color: #f1f1f1
    }
    
    .parent:focus .children {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

```html
<div id="table">
        <div tabindex="0" class="parent">
            <img src="table1.png" alt="table 1"></img>
            <div class="children">You found a paper inside the table.
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="door2_paper.html">Take the paper</a></li>
                    <li><a href="door2.html">Don't take the paper</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div tabindex="0" class="parent">
            <img src="table1.png" alt="table 1"></img>
            <div class="children">You found a paper inside the table.
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="door2_paper.html">Take the paper</a></li>
                    <li><a href="door2.html">Don't take the paper</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div tabindex="0" class="parent">
            <img src="table1.png" alt="table 1"></img>
            <div class="children">You found a paper inside the table.
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="door2_paper.html">Take the paper</a></li>
                    <li><a href="door2.html">Don't take the paper</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div tabindex="0" class="parent">
            <img src="table1.png" alt="table 1"></img>
            <div class="children">You found a paper inside the table.
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="door2_paper.html">Take the paper</a></li>
                    <li><a href="door2.html">Don't take the paper</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately that's not what I mean. What I want is for this image: https://i.imgbox.com/YV6qmZfb.png, a drop down menu will appear only when I click the a table, not the whole picture.
I was able to do a similar thing when I seperate several images and located them, for example like this: https://i.imgbox.com/lO3ETrmt.png, however it was very time-consuming, and 1 additional DIV can force me to relocate all pictures again.

Comment: @Vu Huong well, have you try to used position relative on whole picture, and several small div inside that picture with position absolute?? Give those div accurate height and with, and bind drop-down on those div, then?

Comment: I have followed your instruction, but then I found out that my drop-down menu (div.children) wouldn't appear when there were no image or word in my div.parent to click. I had resolved to use my old method, but thank you very much for your help.